# Undefined complexType 'http://schmeas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array' is used as a base for complex Type restricition

Tags: .net, soap, xsd, wsdl, axis

I'm tryin to get data from an AXIS Service for my .NET Application. So far I am able to gather simple data like int, string ... . But when I try to get Array data like long[] the array only contains the right count of data but only containing zero values instead of the ID's I want.

My WSDL looks like this :

```
        <wsdl:definitions xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:intf="urn:api.broadmail.de/soap11/RpcRecipientList" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns2="http://lang.java" xmlns:impl="urn:api.broadmail.de/soap11/RpcRecipientList" targetNamespace="urn:api.broadmail.de/soap11/RpcRecipientList" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
      <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:api.broadmail.de/soap11/RpcRecipientList">
          <xsd:import namespace="http://lang.java" />
          <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
          <xsd:complexType name="WebserviceException">
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="cause" nillable="true" type="xsd:anyType" />
              <xsd:element name="message" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:complexType name="ArrayOf_xsd_string">
            <xsd:complexContent mixed="false">
              <xsd:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                <xsd:attribute wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[]" ref="soapenc:arrayType" />
              </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:complexContent>
          </xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:complexType name="ArrayOf_xsd_long">
            <xsd:complexContent mixed="false">
              <xsd:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                <xsd:attribute wsdl:arrayType="xsd:long[]" ref="soapenc:arrayType" />
              </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:complexContent>
          </xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfArrayOf_xsd_string">
            <xsd:complexContent mixed="false">
              <xsd:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                <xsd:attribute wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[][]" ref="soapenc:arrayType" />
              </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:complexContent>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:schema>
      </wsdl:types>
      <wsdl:message name="getDataSetRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="in0" type="xsd:string" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="setNameResponse" />
      <wsdl:message name="WebserviceException">
        <wsdl:part name="fault" type="impl:WebserviceException" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="getDescriptionRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="in0" type="xsd:string" />
        <wsdl:part name="in1" type="xsd:long" />
      </wsdl:message>
.....
```

The following lines are underlined when I open it with VS2010 :

```
<xsd:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
```

Saying the following Error :

'Undefined complexType 'http://schmeas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/:Array' is used as a base for complex Type restricition'

I don't get what the Problem ist, and might this be the reason why I only get zero values ? ( I don't mean NULL values btw. ! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours of trying and searching for solutions I maybe found a solution for this Problem. Maybe you guys can be helped with the following link

[Solution 1](http://www.tomergabel.com/GettingWCFAndApacheAxisToBeFriendly.aspx)